# Configure session length with htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, .htaccess

My home web server is running the stock OSX Apache 2 install.  I have some directories with content that I want to secure, so I setup htaccess files for those areas.  However, I find it annoying to have to login to those areas as frequently as I do.  Once I'm logged in I'd like to not have to login again for a long time, similar to setting a long time in a cookie.  But, I'd like to increase the life time of the authenticated session with htaccess.

I've googled but haven't found what I'm looking for, maybe because I'm looking for the wrong term.  I want to configure the 'session length', 'session timeout', 'time limit', or 'expiration' for users authenticated via htaccess.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but pure apache/HTTP authentication gives you no control regarding the browser. After first authentication, your server cannot instruct the browser to logout or timeout, because HTTP authentication doesn't work with session/cookies etc. and the browser will continuously send authentication credentials. To logout you should close the browser.

So, in other words, you cannot do that only from apache.

Regards

Comment: That's a shame, thanks for the info though.  I'll look into using a web interface with cookies to establish a session.

Answer (score 0):

There are hacks which can allow folks to log out of htaccess style auth, but they all have one thing in common - they suck, and they'd be even harder to make work with a timeout.

I know it is easy, but try and avoid this style of auth, you will regret it in future. Perhaps look for a web app that will allow you to get at the files but use a different auth method?